# Most pythonic way if all in iterable if at least one in iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable

Say I want to see if some objects (`a`,`b`,`c`) in an iterable are in object `D`. If none are in `D`, `pass`. If at least one is in `D`, all `a` `b` and `c` must be in `D`, or else an error is raised.

```
 if any(i in D for i in (a,b,c)):
        if all(i in D for i in (a,b,c)):
             # do something 
        else:
             raise Exception
```

Is there a more pythonic/less confusing way of doing this?

Comment: You could extract `(a,b,c)` to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the "x in D" test only once for each element:

```
ins = [i in D for i in (a, b, c)]
if any(ins):
    if all(ins):
         # do something 
    else:
         raise Exception
```

And borrowing phihag's observation about the implication between all and any:

```
ins = [i in D for i in (a, b, c)]
if all(ins):
    # do something
elif any(ins):
    # raise error
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code is already an almost verbatim copy of your logic, so I doubt you can simplify the tests.

Since `all(X)` implies `any(X)` for non-empty X, you can, however, reorder them so that they are not nested:

```
props = (a, b, c)
if all(i in D for i in props):
    # do something
elif any(i in D for i in props):
    raise Exception('Either all or none')
```

Note that I also pulled out `(a, b, c)` into a helper variable, which may or may not improve clarity, depending on the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If `a`, `b`, and `c` are hashable, you can use sets to express this with helpfully-named methods:

```
elements = {a, b, c}
if not elements.isdisjoint(D):
    if elements.issubset(D):
        do_whatever():
    else:
        raise Whatever
```

Comment: @phihag: [That hits the `do_whatever()` case](http://ideone.com/Muaix6).

Answer (score 1):

A compact way to express the condition could be:

```
S = {a, b, c}
if set(D) & S not in (set(), S):
    raise Exception()
```

Comment: This may be very slow though if `D` has a large number of keys.

Comment: That's correct. If `D` is not small it is not a recommended approach.
I also tend to think that the approach that @user2357112 took is more readable than this one, and readability is usually more important than compactness.

Comment: We have to go over all of `D` no matter what, so I don't think there's a speed problem here. There's a potential space problem in `set(D)`, which my code avoids for the `isdisjoint` case, but not for the `not isdisjoint` case (because `issubset` builds a set out of its argument).

Comment: @user2357112 Why do we have to go over all of `D` no matter what? I don't think that's right.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Well, I suppose we could stop early if we find all of `a`, `b`, and `c` before we reach the end, but if we don't, we have to look at all of `D` to figure out which case we're in.

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean with "end"? What's the "end" of a set, for example?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: The end of the iteration over D, whatever the iteration order may be.

Comment: This algorithm will always look at all of D, but a one-pass algorithm that goes over D until it finds all elements of `{a, b, c}` or exhausts all elements of D could stop early sometimes.

Comment: @user2357112 But why iterate over D? Already the OP and the accepted answer don't do that, at least not explicitly. They just use the `in` operator, which for example with sets and dicts *doesn't* iterate the whole thing.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Since the question only talks about iterables and says "if all in iterable if at least one in iterable" in the title, I've been going under the assumption that D is just an iterable, so we can't rely on efficient membership lookup. It sounds like you're working under a different model.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I understand it differently. The problem text says "iterable" only about the to-be-looked-for values. About D it says "object". I believe the title means the same, that it's short for "if all in iterable [are in D]" and "if at least one in iterable [is in D]". That is, "iterable" not referring to D but to the to-be-looked-for values.